# Calculating the sum of means of lists as `n` approaches infinity

Tags: code-review, code-request

I am unable to calculate the sum for larger values of `n`.

```
n = 25
N[Sum[Mean[Table[m/(n^k), {m, 1, (n!)/(k! (n - k)!)}]], {k, 1, n}]]
```

In fact, I wish to calculate the sum as `n` approaches infinity.

Is this possible? How can this be done?

Comment: The `Mean` of your `Table` is always going to be $\frac{1}{2 n^k} \left[ {n \choose k} + 1\right]$, which might help simplify matters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mathematica appears to handle this quite easily.  Your `Mean` of a `Table` can be expressed as a `Sum`

```
mean = 
 Sum[m/(n^k), {m, 1, (n!)/(k! (n - k)!)}]/((n!)/(k! (n - k)!))
(* (n^-k (n! + k! (-k + n)!))/(2 k! (-k + n)!) *)
```

Your sum can then be expressed as

```
sum = Sum[mean, {k, 1, n}]
(* (n^-n (-1 + 2 n^n - (1 + 1/n)^n n^n - n^(
   1 + n) + (1 + 1/n)^n n^(1 + n)))/(2 (-1 + n)) *)
```

Its asymptotic behaviour for large `n` is

```
Asymptotic[sum, n -> ∞]
(* -(1/2) + E/2 *)
```

and it gets quite close to this for modest values of `n`

```
{sum /. n -> 25, Asymptotic[sum, n -> ∞]} // N
(* {0.853751, 0.859141} *)
```

Comment: Also, `Limit[sum, n -> Infinity]`